# Spark Python RDD of lxml.Element objects?

Tags: python, apache-spark, xml-parsing, lxml

I'd like to do some interactive exploration of a set of XML documents. I'm trying to parse the documents using lxml and query using its find, findall, and xpath methods. However PySpark chokes when I try to create the RDD of Element objects:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import XMLSyntaxError
def get_root(xml):
  xml_bytes = bytes(bytearray(xml, encoding = 'utf-8'))
  try:
    return [etree.XML(xml_bytes)]
  except XMLSyntaxError:
    return []

docs = [
    "<doc><tag name='hoo'>hah</tag><tag name='wah'>zoo</tag></doc>"
  , "<doc><tag name='hoo'>yah</tag><tag name='wah'>woo</tag></doc>"
]
roots = [get_root(x)[0] for x in docs]
roots
  [<Element doc at 0x3b2280>, <Element doc at 0x3b2140>]
docs_rdd = sc.parallelize(docs)
roots_rdd = docs_rdd.flatMap(lambda d: get_root(d))
roots_rdd.count()
  2
roots_rdd.first()
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1033, in lxml.etree._Element.__repr__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:42268)
    File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 881, in lxml.etree._Element.tag.__get__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:40855)
    File "apihelpers.pxi", line 15, in lxml.etree._assertValidNode  (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:12875)
  AssertionError: invalid Element proxy at 62728864
```

Can someone help me understand what's going on here?

Python 2.7.x or 3.5.x, Spark 1.6.x, lxml installed with pip or pip3.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`lxml` objects are not serializable and cannot be passed between the executors and the driver or shuffled. It can be easily reproduced without using Spark at all:

```
from lxml import etree
import pickle

pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(etree.XML("<doc>foo</doc>")))
```

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
AssertionError: invalid Element proxy at ...
```

You can still use `lxml` for parsing and fetch serializable Python objects:

```
from operator import attrgetter

docs_rdd.flatMap(get_root).flatMap(lambda x: x).map(attrgetter("text")).collect()
```

```
['hah', 'zoo', 'yah', 'woo']
```